# How to properly bind rvalues to the constructor?

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>


class dummy{
    public:
    //constructor + destructor
    dummy(){
    std::cout<<"dummy constructed"<<std::endl;
    }


    //copy 
    dummy(const dummy& o){
    std::cout<<"dummy copy init"<<std::endl;
    }


    void operator=(const&dummy){
    std::cout<<"dummy copy operator"<<std::endl;
    }

    //moves
    dummy(dummy&& other){
    std::cout<<"dummy move init"<<std::endl;        
    }

    void operator=(dummy&&){
    std::cout<<"dummy move copy"<<std::endl;
    }

};



class test{
    public:
    dummy d;

    test(dummy&& d):d(std::move(d)){
    std::cout<<"test"<<std::endl;   
    }
};




int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    test m(dummy());        //prints NOTHING.
    test t(std::move(dummy()));

    return 0;
}
```

using `test m(dummy());`

**Output:** nothing

using `test t(std::move(dummy()));`

**Output:**

```
dummy constructed
dummy move init
test
```

Which is something that is expected.

So my question is that,

Is it mandatory to use `std::move` if the parameter is `type&&`? 
and isn't `dummy()` considered as an rvalue so why do i need to use `std::move` ? I am somehow confused about binding rvalues to rvalue references and i would like to need some clarification.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test m(dummy());` declares a function called `m`.  You probably meant:

```
test m{ dummy{} };
```

which declares a variable `m` passing a temporary `dummy`.

Comment: Eh weird, why brackets though? aren't they meant for `initializer list` ?

Comment: @CarloBrew the `(` is ambiguous as to whether it is a function parameter list, or an argument list.  However `{` can only be an argument list. The braces can be used in any situation of providing initializers to an object.